# Howto make xamarin forms relayout if the size of my native control changes

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on a control deriving from Entry in xamarin forms with a native renderer for iOS and Android.

Depending on some options, the size of the control can change (there is a text line added or removed from the control).

This basically works as long as I do not do the size change of the control when it is already displayed.

When I do the size change when it is already displayed, the outer layout (in my test case a StackLayout) does not move the widgets accordingly. When the size is reduced, the free space is not taken by the next controls. When the size is expanded, the control is drawn below the next controls.

Can I somehow tell my custom control that its size has changed and that it has to be re-layouted on the page?

Comment: Did you try to change the IsVisible property instead of the size? You can bind the visibility property to a bool and change that bool when you need to show/hide the Entry.